# I want to have months along my X-axis in sync with my data

Tags: matlab

I want to have my x-axis representing the month that corresponds to my data.

I have 3468 data points in my Y-Values, which represent 289(data-points) * 12(months).

I want my X-axis to show the months from January to December.

How can I achieve this, I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use the function xticks to specify the x-axis locations where you want to add the x-axis labels. Here, since you have 289 data points per month. I would choose the middle point (145) for each month to add the labels.

```
 y = randn(1, 289 * 12);
 plot(y)
 xticks(145:289:289 * 12)
```

Second, you can use the function xticklabels to specify the actual labels that would like to add.

```
xticklabels({'Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'})
```

Equivalently, you could do the following:

```
 mth = datetime(2017,1,1)+calmonths(0:12);
 xticklabels(month(mth,'name'))
 xtickangle(45)
```